# What are Prisms?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm trying to achieve a deeper understanding of `lens` library, so I play around with the types it offers. I have already had some experience with lenses, and know how powerful and convenient they are. So I moved on to Prisms, and I'm a bit lost. It seems that prisms allow two things:

1. Determining if an entity belongs to a particular branch of a sum type, and if it does, capturing the underlying data in a tuple or a singleton.
2. Destructuring and reconstructing an entity, possibly modifying it in process.

The first point seems useful, but usually one doesn't need all the data from an entity, and `^?` with plain lenses allows getting `Nothing` if the field in question doesn't belong to the branch the entity represents, just like it does with prisms.

The second point... I don't know, might have uses?

So the question is: what can I do with a Prism that I can't with other optics?

**Edit**: thank you everyone for excellent answers and links for further reading! I wish I could accept them all.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the title of your question. Hope you don’t mind!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Lenses characterise the *has-a* relationship; Prisms characterise the *is-a* relationship.**

A `Lens s a` says "`s` *has an* `a`"; it has methods to get exactly one `a` from an `s` and to overwrite exactly one `a` in an `s`. A `Prism s a` says "`a` *is an* `s`"; it has methods to upcast an `a` to an `s` and to (attempt to) downcast an `s` to an `a`.

Putting that intuition into code gives you the familiar "get-set" (or "costate comonad coalgebra") formulation of lenses,

```
data Lens s a = Lens {
    get :: s -> a,
    set :: a -> s -> s
}
```

and an "upcast-downcast" representation of prisms,

```
data Prism s a = Prism {
    up :: a -> s,
    down :: s -> Maybe a
}
```

`up` injects an `a` into `s` (without adding any information), and `down` tests whether the `s` is an `a`.

In `lens`, `up` is spelled [`review`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Review.html#v:review) and `down` is [`preview`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:preview). There’s no `Prism` constructor; you use [the `prism'` smart constructor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:prism-39-).

---

What can you do with a `Prism`? Inject and project sum types!

```
_Left :: Prism (Either a b) a
_Left = Prism {
    up = Left,
    down = either Just (const Nothing)
}
_Right :: Prism (Either a b) b
_Right = Prism {
    up = Right,
    down = either (const Nothing) Just
}
```

Lenses don't support this - you can't write a `Lens (Either a b) a` because you can't implement `get :: Either a b -> a`. As a practical matter, you *can* write a `Traversal (Either a b) a`, but that doesn't allow you to create an `Either a b` from an `a` - it'll only let you overwrite an `a` which is already there.

> **Aside:** I think this subtle point about `Traversal`s is the source of your confusion about partial record fields.
>
> > `^?` with plain lenses allows getting `Nothing` if the field in question doesn't belong to the branch the entity represents
>
> Using `^?` with a real `Lens` will never return `Nothing`, because a `Lens s a` identifies exactly one `a` inside an `s`.
> When confronted with a partial record field,
>
> ```
> data Wibble = Wobble { _wobble :: Int } | Wubble { _wubble :: Bool }
> ```
>
> `makeLenses` will generate a `Traversal`, not a `Lens`.
>
> ```
> wobble :: Traversal' Wibble Int
> wubble :: Traversal' Wibble Bool
> ```

For an example of this how `Prism`s can be applied in practice, look to [`Control.Exception.Lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Exception-Lens.html), which provides a collection of `Prism`s into Haskell's extensible `Exception` hierarchy. This lets you perform runtime type tests on `SomeException`s and inject specific exceptions into `SomeException`.

```
_ArithException :: Prism' SomeException ArithException
_AsyncException :: Prism' SomeException AsyncException
-- etc.
```

(These are slightly simplified versions of the actual types. In reality these prisms are overloaded class methods.)

Thinking at a higher level, certain whole programs can be thought of as being "basically a `Prism`". Encoding and decoding data is one example: you can always convert structured data to a `String`, but not every `String` can be parsed back:

```
showRead :: (Show a, Read a) => Prism String a
showRead = Prism {
    up = show,
    down = listToMaybe . fmap fst . reads
}
```

To summarise, `Lens`es and `Prism`s together encode the two core design tools of object-oriented programming: composition and subtyping. `Lens`es are a first-class version of Java's `.` and `=` operators, and `Prism`s are a first-class version of Java's `instanceof` and implicit upcasting.

---

One fruitful way of thinking about `Lens`es is that they give you a way of splitting up a composite `s` into a focused value `a` and some context `c`. Pseudocode:

```
type Lens s a = exists c. s <-> (a, c)
```

In this framework, a `Prism` gives you a way to look at an `s` as being either an `a` or some context `c`.

```
type Prism s a = exists c. s <-> Either a c
```

(I'll leave it to you to convince yourself that these are isomorphic to the simple representations I demonstrated above. Try implementing `get`/`set`/`up`/`down` for these types!)

In this sense a `Prism` is a *co-`Lens`*. `Either` is the categorical dual of `(,)`; `Prism` is the categorical dual of `Lens`.

You can also observe this duality in the ["profunctor optics"](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/jeremy.gibbons/publications/poptics.pdf) formulation - [`Strong`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2.2/docs/Data-Profunctor.html#t:Strong) and [`Choice`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2.2/docs/Data-Profunctor.html#t:Choice) are dual.

```
type Lens  s t a b = forall p. Strong p => p a b -> p s t
type Prism s t a b = forall p. Choice p => p a b -> p s t
```

This is *more or less* the representation which `lens` uses, because these `Lens`es and `Prism`s are very composable. You can compose `Prism`s to get bigger `Prism`s ("`a` *is an* `s`, which *is a* `p`") using `(.)`; composing a `Prism` with a `Lens` gives you a `Traversal`.

Comment: That first line alone cleared up so much confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

I just wrote a blog post, which might help build some intuition about Prisms: *Prisms are constructors* (Lenses are fields). http://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2018-06-19-prisms-are-constructors.html

---

Prisms could be introduced as *first-class pattern matching*, but that is a
one-sided view. I'd say they are **generalised constructors**, though maybe
more often used for pattern matching than for actual construction.

The important property of constructors (and *lawful prisms*), is their
injectivity.  Though the usual prism laws don't state that directly,
injectivity property can be deduced.

To quote `lens`-library documentation, the prisms laws are:

First, if I `review` a value with a `Prism` and then `preview`, I will get it back:

```
preview l (review l b) ≡ Just b
```

Second, if you can extract a value a using a `Prism` `l` from a value `s`, then
the value `s` is completely described by `l` and `a`:

```
preview l s ≡ Just a ⇒ review l a ≡ s
```

In fact, the first law alone is enough to prove the injectivity of construction
via `Prism`:

```
review l x ≡ review l y ⇒ x ≡ y
```

The proof is straight-forward:

```
review l x ≡ review l y
  -- x ≡ y -> f x ≡ f y
preview l (review l x) ≡ preview l (review l y)
  -- rewrite both sides with the first law
Just x ≡ Just y
  -- injectivity of Just
x ≡ y
```

We can use injectivity property as an additional tool in the equational
reasoning toolbox. Or we can use it as a easy property to check to decide
whether something is a lawful `Prism`.  The check is easy as we only the
`review` side of `Prism`. Many *smart constructors*, which for example
normalise the input data, aren't lawful prisms.

An example using [`case-insensitive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/case-insensitive-1.2.0.11):

```
-- Bad!
_CI :: FoldCase s => Prism' (CI s) s
_CI = prism' ci (Just . foldedCase)

λ> review _CI "FOO" == review _CI "foo"
True

λ> "FOO" == "foo"
False
```

The first law is also violated:

```
λ> preview _CI (review _CI "FOO")
Just "foo"
```

Comment: Very nice. So far if I understand correctly we've just shown that the `review` operation of every lawful prism is an injection. Can we also go the other way and show that every injection induces a lawful prism?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin not every injection induces a prism. We need so called "decidable embedding (injection)". In fact these are equivalent: the decidability requirement is essentially asking to give the `preview` / `match` part of the prism. A non-haskell example is an injection into `Type`. A Haskell example of non-decidable injection could be `forward :: (Integer -> Natural) -> (Integer -> Integer); forward f = toInteger . f`. Given a `g :: Integer -> Integer`, you need to test for all `n :: Integer` that `g n` is non-negative. That is not computable.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the other excellent answers, I feel `Iso`s provide a nice vantage point for considering this matter.

- There being some `i :: Iso' s a` means if you have an `s` value you also (virtually) have an `a` value, and vice versa. The `Iso'` gives you two conversion functions, `view i :: s -> a` and `review i :: a -> s` which are both guaranteed to succeed and lossless.
- There being some `l :: Lens' s a` means if you have an `s` you also have an `a`, *but not vice versa*. `view l :: s -> a` may drop information along the way, as the conversion isn't required to be lossless, and so you can't go the other way if all you have is an `a` (cf. `set l :: a -> s -> s`, which also requires an `s` in addition to the `a` value in order to provide the missing information).
- There being some `p :: Prism' s a` means if you have an `s` value you *might* also have an `a`, but there are no guarantees. The conversion `preview p :: s -> Maybe a` is not guaranteed to succeed. Still, you do have the other direction, `review p :: a -> s`.

In other words, an `Iso` is invertible and always succeeds. If you drop the invertibility requirement, you get a `Lens`; if you drop the success guarantee, you get a `Prism`. If you drop both, you get an [affine traversal](http://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2017-04-18-glassery.html#s:17) (which is not in *lens* as a separate type), and if you go a step further and give up on having at most one target you end up with a `Traversal`. That is reflected in one of the diamonds of [the *lens* subtype hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKQmE.png):

```
 Traversal
    / \
   /   \
  /     \
Lens   Prism
  \     /
   \   /
    \ /
    Iso
```