# How to do mapMaybe using lenses

Tags: haskell, fold, haskell-lens, aeson, lenses

I am using `wreq` on the github api to get a list of files in a repository. I include this for completeness sake. This isn't about doing the web request:

```hs
    let
        myOpts = defaults
          &  header "Accept" .~ ["application/vnd.github.raw"]
          &  header "X-GitHub-Api-Version" .~ ["2022-11-28"]

        url = "https://api.github.com/repos/rubenmoor/learn-palantype/git/trees/main?recursive=1"

    liftIO (try $ getWith (myOpts & auth .~ mAuth) $ Text.unpack url) <&> \case
      Left (HttpExceptionRequest _ content) -> Error 500 $ Text.pack $ show content
      Left (InvalidUrlException u msg) -> Error 500 $ "Url " <> Text.pack u <> " invalid: " <> Text.pack msg
      Right resp -> -- ...
```

The `resp` is a JSON-encoded and looks something like this (only in reality a lot more files):

```json
{
  "sha": "7fd9d59c9b101261ca500827eb9d6b4c4421431b",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/rubenmoor/learn-palantype/git/trees/7fd9d59c9b101261ca500827eb9d6b4c4421431b",
  "tree": [
    {
      "path": ".github",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type": "tree",
      "sha": "eb21b416a406ebae963116911afd3cd0994132ce",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/rubenmoor/learn-palantype/git/trees/eb21b416a406ebae963116911afd3cd0994132ce"
    },
    {
      "path": ".gitignore",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "a47bd530c4b8677af24b291b7c401202ca1170d4",
      "size": 186,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/rubenmoor/learn-palantype/git/blobs/a47bd530c4b8677af24b291b7c401202ca1170d4"
    },
    {
      "path": "static.nix",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "fcac7837dc13cce9368517ba8ba49a00d5b76734",
      "size": 353,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/rubenmoor/learn-palantype/git/blobs/fcac7837dc13cce9368517ba8ba49a00d5b76734"
    },
    {
      "path": "cms-content/SystemDE/EN/Introduction.md",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "25b2be5dd3fd3d2a7a1c8fc95ed7e9623e7bd5c6",
      "size": 2670,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/rubenmoor/learn-palantype/git/blobs/25b2be5dd3fd3d2a7a1c8fc95ed7e9623e7bd5c6"
    },
    {
      "path": "cms-content/SystemDE/EN/Pattern Overview.md",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "c34f97e9666e56ec12e554afc7f684e9666b74fd",
      "size": 18,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/rubenmoor/learn-palantype/git/blobs/c34f97e9666e56ec12e554afc7f684e9666b74fd"
    }
  ],
  "truncated": false
}
```

Now I can use `Data.Aeson.Lens` to go into the json structure like this:

```hs
resp ^. responseBody . key "tree" ^.. -- ???
```

Now comes the tricky part.
I am only interested in markdown files inside a directory called "cms-content", or subdirectories thereof.
Files have the value "blob" at the key "type".
And for those files, I want their full path w/o the filetype extension.
So, given the example JSON, I am looking for this result

```hs
["SystemDE/EN/Introduction", "SystemDE/EN/Pattern Overview"] :: [Text]
```

I think of `mapMaybe` and can define a suitable function like that:

```hs
maybeCMSFile :: Text -> Text -> Maybe Text
maybeCMSFile strType strPath | strType == "blob" =
    case Text.stripPrefix "cms-content/" strPath of
        Nothing  -> Nothing
        Just suf -> Text.stripSuffix ".md" strPath
maybeCMSFile _ _ = Nothing
```

The arguments for `maybeCMSFile` are values for specific keys of the objects in the JSON array:

```hs
\o -> maybeCMSFile (o ^. key "type" . _String) (o ^. key "path" . _String)
```

But instead of converting the JSON array into a list (`_Array` from Data.Aeson.Lens gets me there) and running `mapMaybe maybeCMSFile . Vector.toList`, I am looking for a way to use lenses to the same end.
I can simplify the problem for myself quite a bit by breaking things down in simpler steps:

1. filter for the key/value "type": "blob"
2. filter for the suffix ".md" in the value at key "path"
3. extract the filepath without the suffix "cms-content" and without the prefix ".md"

But of course I am wondering, if this can all be done just combining the right lenses.

---

Let me add that I am well aware that this question is awfully specific.
Personally, I learned my way around lenses by these kind of examples.
I still have troubles reading the type signatures and making sense of the lenses (and prisms) with the help of the documentation on hackage alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor variation on your not-compiling code:

```hs
resp ^.. responseBody . key "tree" . _Array . each
  . filteredBy (key "type" . _String . only "blob")
  . key "path" . _String
  . filtered (\str -> "cms-content/" `Text.isPrefixOf` str && ext `Text.isSuffixOf` str)
  . folding (Text.stripPrefix "cms-content/" >=> Text.stripSuffix ext)
```

Comment: very nice. turns out `filteredBy` is not a problem. ^.. just ignores the index?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75883507/2751851):

> is there such a thing as half a prism?

A half-prism with only the forward, fallible part [amounts to a traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50919684/2751851). In fact, that already is how [`filteredBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2.2/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:filteredBy) is being used in the work-in-progress solution at the end of your answer. `filteredBy p` is a traversal which ignores a value if `preview p` on it is `Nothing`.

We can also apply this the idea to the second part of your ([or DDub's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75894506/2751851)) solution, by using the [`prefixed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2.2/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#t:Prefixed) and [`suffixed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2.2/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#t:Suffixed) prisms as traversals:

```
fileList :: Value -> [Text]
fileList body =
    body ^.. key "tree" . _Array . each
        . filteredBy (key "type" . _String . only "blob")
        . key "path" . _String
        . prefixed "cms-content/" . suffixed ".md"
```

---

P.S.: Lensifying `mapMaybe` itself, in a way that allows you to directly supply an `a -> Maybe b` function to a combinator instead of encoding it as a prism or traversal, is nontrivial, and would require extra machinery not included in *lens*. Two explorations of the problem space are Chris Penner's [*Composable filters using Witherable optics*](https://chrispenner.ca/posts/witherable-optics) and Oleg Grenrus' [*Coindexed optics*](https://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2021-01-04-coindexed-optics.html).

Comment: So in my case, a lensified mapMaybe isn't needed. `prefixed` and `suffixed` are pretty elegant and there definition makes sense: `prefixed p = prism' (p <>) (TS.stripPrefix p)`. It seems the mapMaybe functionality is built in into lenses. Why is a `_Just` prism not need?

Comment: @ruben.moor The target of e.g. `prefixed` is `Text` rather than `Maybe Text`, so there's no need to dig further into it with an additional `_Just`. A prism (or a fallible traversal) already incorporates the possibility of failure that is expressed by the `Maybe` result type of `stripPrefix`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and I found this solution:

```hs
_MarkdownFile :: Text -> Prism Value Value Text Text
_MarkdownFile ext = prism fromFile toFile
  where
    -- not needed in practice, is there such a thing as half a prism?
    fromFile str = object
      [ "type" .= ("blob" :: Text)
      , "path" .= ("cms-content" <> str)
      ]
    toFile   o   = case o ^. key "type" . _String of
      "blob" -> let path = o ^. key "path" . _String
                in  bool (Left o) (Right path) $ checkStr path
      _ -> Left o
    checkStr str =
         "cms-content/" `Text.isPrefixOf` str
      && ext            `Text.isSuffixOf` str

getFileList :: Text -> Handler (Response [Text])
getFileList ext = do
    mAuth <- asks toMAuth
    let
        url = "https://api.github.com/repos/rubenmoor/learn-palantype/git/trees/main?recursive=1"

    liftIO (try $ getWith (myOpts & auth .~ mAuth) $ Text.unpack url) <&> \case

      Left (HttpExceptionRequest _ content) ->
        Error 500 $ Text.pack $ show content

      Left (InvalidUrlException u msg)      ->
        Error 500 $ "Url " <> Text.pack u <> " invalid: " <> Text.pack msg
      Right resp                            ->
        Success $ resp ^.. responseBody . key "tree" . _Array . each . _MarkdownFile ext
```

However, `_MarkdownFile` shouldn' be a prism.
I don't know what it is.

So this version, actually using `mapMaybe` makes more sense to me:

```hs
getFileList :: Text -> Handler (Response [Text])
getFileList ext = do
    mAuth <- asks toMAuth
    let
        url = "https://api.github.com/repos/rubenmoor/learn-palantype/git/trees/main?recursive=1"

    liftIO (try $ getWith (myOpts & auth .~ mAuth) $ Text.unpack url) <&> \case

      Left (HttpExceptionRequest _ content) ->
        Error 500 $ Text.pack $ show content

      Left (InvalidUrlException u msg)      ->
        Error 500 $ "Url " <> Text.pack u <> " invalid: " <> Text.pack msg
      Right resp                            ->
        Success $ mapMaybe maybeCMSFile $
          resp ^.. responseBody . key "tree" . _Array . each
  where
    maybeCMSFile o =
        case o ^. key "type" . _String of
          "blob" -> let path = o ^. key "path" . _String
                    in  bool Nothing (Just path) $ checkStr path
          _ -> Nothing
    checkStr str =
         "cms-content/" `Text.isPrefixOf` str
      && ext            `Text.isSuffixOf` str
```

But the actual question remains: Is there a way to do this in a lense-like fashion?

---

EDIT:

This code doesn't compile, but this is how I imagine a lens solution:

```hs
    resp ^.. responseBody . key "tree" . _Array . each
            . filteredBy (key "type" . _String . only "blob") -- index (), how to discard?
            . filteredBy (_Path . filtered                    -- index ?, how to discard?
                (\str -> "cms-content/" `Text.isPrefixOf` str -- filtered expects a fold
                      && ext `Text.isSuffixOf` str
                )) . _Path
  where
    _Path = key "path" . _String
```

Comment: A half-prism with just the fallible direction is a traversal. (More precisely, it would be an affine traversal, as it can reach at most one target, but *lens* doesn't capture that distinction.)